# How to get the total number of ethereum addresses who have interacted with a smart contract programatically?

Tags: ethers.js

I want to show the total number of users who have interacted with the forsage smart contract on my website. I just need the total number of unique users. How do I get that?

Answer (score 0):

Users can interact with a smart contract several ways.

So which is the interaction that you would like to keep trace?
If you already known the actions, then add a listener into it and count.

If the contract deployed for a long time, then you can consider to crawl data from sites like: etherscan or bscscan.

Comment: users interact with contract through https://forsage.io/b/k4gvpe/